# use variable to reference a document in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, variables, document

Here is my statement in mongodb:

```
var target = db.test.find({},{_id:1}).sort({_id:-1}).limit(1);
```

which can give me the largest `_id`. When I type **target** in shell, the output is like this:

```
> target
{ "_id" : ObjectId("51e062189c6ae665454e301d") }
```

However, when I type target again, nothing returns. Also, when I use target in other queries, those queries don't work either. Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 0):

This is most probably because **target** becomes a cursor since it is a result of `.find()`. However you can still obtain the resulting document by using `toArray()` method of MongoDB cursor like the following:

```
> var target = db.test.find({},{_id:1}).sort({_id:-1}).limit(1).toArray()
> if (target.length > 0) { target = target[0]; } else { target = null; }
```

You may find some information on `toArray` **[here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.toArray/#cursor.toArray)**.

Comment: No problem - I had the same issue some time ago :) I'm glad it helped.